# Comparing values in two hashes

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble in comparing values in two hashes, getting the error "Can't convert String into Integer".
First hash has values captured from a web page using the method "capture_page_data(browser)" and the second hash has data parsed from a report.

Code looks like below:

```
# Open the web application 
# Navigate to a specific page and capture page data

loan_data = Hash.new

loan_data = capture_page_data(browser)
```

Second hash has values captured from a report generated from the web application.
Code looks like below:

```
@report_data[page] = Hash.new
# we have written some logic to parse the data from the report into hash variable
```

Now I am trying to compare the values in theses two hashes to ensure the data in report is matching with the data in application using below code which is giving me the error "Can't convert String into Integer".

```
loan_data.map{|ld| ld['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName']} &
      @report_data.map{|rd| rd['Relationship']}
```

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Regards,

Veera.

Comment: Setting `loan_data = Hash.new` is pointless here, because it will be overwritten immediately anyway. You can just leave that line out.

Comment: Thanks padde, you are correct. I left that line out now.

Comment: You seem to be missing some basic ruby/programming understanding. You might consider doing some tutorials. Also, get to know `irb`. It lets you try experiments and see what is going to work for you without rerunning all your code. Also if you write unit tests, this also lets you verify each small part of your code making the steps you are taking small and fast. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash#map` iterates through the hash like it was an array of key/value pairs.

```
{a:1,b:2}.map{|x| puts x.inspect }
# prints 
# [:a,1]
# [:b,2]

{a:1,b:2}.map{|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
# prints 
# a => 1
# b => 2
```

It applies the block you provide to each pair *and* collects the results into a new array.

```
result = {a:1,b:2}.map{|k,v| "#{k} => #{v}" }
puts result.inspect
# prints 
# [ "a => 1", "b => 2" ]
```

I would guess what you are trying to do is compare a single key from each array... in which case...

```
if loan_data[:id][:span]['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblR‌​elName'] == @report_data[1]['Relationship']
  log_message("pass")
else
  log_message("fail")
end
```

might be what you are trying to do.. but I am only guessing.

It all depends on the shape of your data.

Comment: Thank you Nigel, your guess is correct. I am trying to compare a single key from each Hash/array. code suggested by you worked fine but I am not getting any result in the execution log i.e pass/fail. shall i include if condition like --if loan_data['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName'] &
  @report_data['Relationship']
log_message("pass") else log_message ("fail")

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I have updated the code a little bit which looks like-- if ("#{loan_data[:id][:span]   ['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName']}" & "#{@report_data[1]['Relationship']}")
    passed_to_log("Relationship name in the application is matching with the Relationship name in report ")
  else failed_to_log("Relationship name in the application is not matching with the Relationship name in report ")end, this is giving me a different error now 'undefined method `&' for "POC_Reports_test":String'. I tried to pass the values of these hashes to the log which are matchi

Comment: I tried to pass the values of these hashes to the log which are exactly matching. I have used the below code to pass the values passed_to_log("Relationship name in application is #{loan_data[:id][:span]['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName']}")
passed_to_log("Relationship name in report is #{@report_data[1]['Relationship']}") both are passing the same value i.e.POC_Reports_test to the log. Can you please suggest me how to compare these values.

Comment: Assuming them are both of the same type, you can just `==` them. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the `ld` variable inside your block, you will find that it is an array.  You can get an element of it with `ld[0]` or `ld[1]`, but `ld[string]` does not make sense and results in the exception you are seeing.  The `ld` array will actually be an array with two elements: key and value.

Comment: Thanks David, When I checked the execution log I can find the values of the first hash 'loan_data' as loan_data--- :span:     MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName: POC_Reports_test and the values of the second hash 'report_data' as @report_data--- 1: Relationship: POC_Reports_test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.. but I found a different solution to compare a single key from two hashes/Arrays using the below code which worked fine.

string_equals?(loan_data[:id][:span]['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName'], @report_data[1]['Relationship'] )

Thanks,

Veera.

Answer (score -1):

It's best to debug the content of loan_data and @report_data directly, but you can try .to_sym to convert the key into symbol.

```
loan_data.map{|ld| ld['MainContent_cphContent_LoanOverViewGeneralInfoCtrl_lblRelName'.to_sym]} &
@report_data.map{|rd| rd['Relationship'.to_sym]}
```

Comment: I can't see how this will help as loan_data is supposed to be a Hash, ld will be an array

Comment: My bad, sorry for the wrong answer. I think Nigel has the best answer.